# How to design tree in meteor framework?

Tags: html, meteor, frameworks

I do not how know to design a tree in meteor framework? I want to make one in html and bind data from MongoDB.

How do I begin?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it several ways. Here are some of them:

- You can use [jstree](http://www.jstree.com), see a full example with meteor here: https://github.com/tobkle/meteor-jstree-example
- You can do it manually, it is not so difficult but you will have to implement every feature yourself (drag&drop for instance). Here is a tutorial: http://meteorpedia.com/read/Trees
- You can use kendo UI in your meteor app. See an example and a demo here: https://github.com/awatson1978/json-treeview

Feel free to complete your question, I'll edit the answer if necessary.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Billybobbonnet, can you tell me steps to use this?